# Save QuickTime movie trailer files to computer without Pro

Tags: quicktime, video-playback

Is it true that a few months ago, QuickTime allows users to save the movie trailers without using the Pro version?

Right now, it seems like we need to pay $29.99 to save the movie trailer clip onto the hard drive.

Several months ago, I also tried using Ubuntu and there was a plugin to view the movie trailer and was able to save it too.

Are there other ways to save it to the hard drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two things to download trailers.

1. Modify the url. Example:

   > http://movies.apple.com/movies/fox/avatar/avatar-fte1_720p.mov

   becomes:

   > http://movies.apple.com/movies/fox/avatar/avatar-fte1_h720p.mov

   Notice the added **h**.
2. Change the user agent string.

   I use [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) to download trailers (if you've got OS X or Linux, you've already got it, the link there is for Windows). Use a user agent string from Quicktime, so you type:

   ```
    wget -U QuickTime/7.6.2 http://movies.apple.com/movies/fox/avatar/avatar-fte1_h720p.mov
   ```

Answer (score -1):

View source on the page displaying the .mov, copy the full URL of the .mov file into a new browser window, let the .mov load all the way, then Save as...

Other QuickTime tricks here: [Hacker's Guide to QuickTime](http://home.sol.se/michael/qtguide/#topic_savefrombrowser)

Comment: thanks.  that page is nice to read.  if the address, for example, http://movies.apple.com/movies/magnolia_pictures/wonderfulworld/wonderfulworld-tlr1_720p.mov is typed into Firefox or Chrome, then the movie plays...  but when it is File -> Save, then only about 1k is saved into the hard drive.  If right click movie and Save, then it asks for upgrading to Pro also.  Could it be that the plugin also requires upgrading to Pro to save now?

Comment: Wait for the movie to play completely, which may take a while, then right click in the browser window and Save as... Works for me in Safari.

Comment: It doesn't work. It doesn't work on the Mac. And on 32 bit Win 7, it didn't work, and I downloaded and installed the latest Safari 4.0.4 and QuickTime 7.6.4 bundle and it didn't work. Quicktime wanted to upgrade itself to 7.6.5 and so I upgraded that, and after the upgrade, it didn't work either. It tried to save a "wonderfulworld-tlr1_720p.mov.qt" to the hard drive but in fact didn't save anything. I checked the folder, and also if I save it again and again it didn't ask whether I want to replace the file, so that previously saved file really didn't exist.

Comment: There's better ways than this :)