# How to detect the real download link for a embedded quicktime video?

Tags: mac, video, quicktime

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Youtube and Google video downloaders ?](https://superuser.com/questions/6675/youtube-and-google-video-downloaders)
>   [How to save QuickTime movie trailer files?](https://superuser.com/questions/76359/how-to-save-quicktime-movie-trailer-files)

http://movies.apple.com/media/us/ipad/2010/tours/apple-ipad-guidedtour-playall-us-20100329_r848-9cie.mov

like this one for example.

Comment: you tried that on the link?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that was not a typical .mov file. Comment removed.

Comment: I guess the answers are in "Youtube and Google video downloaders ?" at http://superuser.com/questions/6675/youtube-and-google-video-downloaders (and many other questions that refer to, for example DownloadHelper: http://superuser.com/search?q=DownloadHelper)

Comment: Or this maybe? http://superuser.com/questions/76359/how-to-save-quicktime-movie-trailer-files

Comment: Any solution doesn't involve a download plugin on a mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above .mov file is like a play list with links to various versions of the video that are intended for different types of device.

You can simply open the file in in a text editor (such as Notepad) and copy & paste the file names to get directly to the desired file.

Here are the filenames from the .mov play list:

- apple-ipad-guidedtour-playall-us-20100329_848x480.mov
- apple-ipad-guidedtour-playall-us-20100329_e320x180.3gp
- apple-ipad-guidedtour-playall-us-20100329_i320x180.m4v

Simply append them to the original URL (e.g. http://movies.apple.com/media/us/ipad/2010/tours/apple-ipad-guidedtour-playall-us-20100329_848x480.mov)